# android webapp remote framework?

Tags: android, cordova, client, remote-access

For some kind of student/teacher/eLearning scenario, i have the following question:
I have ten android devices (students), running a webapp based on phonegap/html5/javascript/jquery.

I want a PC (the teacher) to
- fetch data from the devices
- send data/files to the devices
(- control the webapp remotely)

What i'd like to avoid:
- the need to run and administrate a webserver (e.g. apache), or similar complicated to setup tools, on the PC

Can anybody help out, what technique, tools or frameworks i may look for?

The webapp itself is similar to a survey/quiz.
Me personally, i would choose to install an apache server, but the teacher needs an easier to handle solution.
Thanks in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something of a server to send the data.

If you can't provide this yourself, you could make up some easy work arounds using webservices from others. Per example dropbox (public folder), Google Drive, Email  etc.

Comment: I'm indeed looking for some kind of 'server', i'm just wondering, if there are solutions out there, which may be more easy to handle than the server solutions that i know (apache, mongoose) or which don't require a skilled administrator.


Web or cloud services are no solution either, because the application needs to run in a VPN without internet connection.

Comment: How do you plan on communicating with devices without any internet connection?

Comment: It does not require an internet connection to communicate between two devices. In this case, it's simply via wlan.